# Winforms data binding challenge

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding

I have two formula.

```
a = sqrt ( b )
```

and it's inverse

```
b = a ^ 2
```

I want two edit boxes with the value for a in one edit box and the value for b in the other. If I manually edit either edit box the other is updated according to the above formula. To make the problem trickier the edit boxes should be limited to showing two decimal places only and the update of the other textbox should be activated only after pressing enter or losing focus on the current text box being edited. It should also be impossible to enter invalid values ( no numeric ) in.

Individually each little piece doesn't seem to be a problem but tying all requirements together I just can't get my head around.

Note the values of a and b should be data bound properties on some object.

Answer (score 0):

If the dual update is what is giving you problems.

```
private double? a;
private double? b;
public double? A
{
    get
    {
        return a;
    }
    set
    {
        if (a == value) return;
        a = value;
        if (a == null) b = null; else b = a * a;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("A");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("B");
    }
}

public double? B
{
    get
    {
        return b;
    }
    set
    {
        if (b == value) return;
        b = value;
        if (b == null) b = null; else a = Math.Sqrt((double)b);
        NotifyPropertyChanged("A");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("B");
    }
}
```

Comment: No the dual update is not what is giving me problems. It is the whole package which is giving problems. I'll add some code samples later. I didn't have them handy why I posted the question on the handy. However the problem for me is that I'm using the parse and format events to do the formatting to 2 decimal places and everytime I hit a key in the edit box it processes it immediately, does the binding, fires a parse event and *then* a format event and reformats the field I'm editing and I lose the insert position.

Comment: Though now I think of it this code is part of some legacy code base and its possible there is some nasty extra key handling hanging around where I don't expect it causing me problems.